# Lower Namespace to 2.6 in Flash Builder

Tags: flash, build, namespaces, air, flash-builder

I have to build an Adobe AIR application with the Namespace 2.6. The problem is, I recently downloaded Flash Builder 4.6 onto a new computer, and it requires the Namespace to be 3.1. Otherwise, it throws an error. The only solutions I can find online are to change the Namespace in the app.xml file to 3.1. This however causes issues later on when I try to Code-sign the application.

The easiest fix would be to make Flash Builder build the application with Namespace 2.6. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

To my best knowledge, it's not possible to downgrade with the version of SDK that you have (I don't know what Adobe was thinking when giving versions, as it is redundant if you think about it...). Yet you could definitely download an older version of the SDK [here](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Downloads) and then merge / replace your current SDK.